# setFullScreenWindow(null) not working in MAC os x Swing application

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I am working on Swing application which has feature to go full screen. On any key event I am trying to exit the full screen window using setFullScreenWindow(null), but it doesn't work. 
 here's code.

Code for setting JFrame full screen

```
frame.getJMenuBar().setVisible(false);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
```

Code for exiting full screen on key event:

```
@Override
        protected void process(List<Boolean> chunks) {
            for(Boolean b:chunks){
                System.out.println(b);
                if(b){
                    if(timer !=null)
                        timer.stop();
                    Window window = gd.getFullScreenWindow();
                    if(window != null){
                        window.dispose();
                    }
                    gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);

                    frame.getJMenuBar().setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

please advice. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before setting the full screen window null you need to check whether the full screen is supported or not like below::

```
if(gd.isFullScreenSupported())
       gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
```

it works perfectly now :)